# Cypress wait command in each loop

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have an array of codes for api calls. I need to stop the each loop based on the api call response.
Desired outcome: each loop stops after resolve returns false;
Current outcome: error, function returns promise that never resolves;

```
cy.wrap(array).each(function(code, index, arr) {

     return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
        cy.intercept('GET', ApiUrl + code).as(`searchApi${code}`);
        cy.get('input').type(code); // Sends the api request
        
        cy.wait(`@searchApi${code}`).then(({ request, response }) => {
          
          resolve(response.body.IsAcceptedForCollection);
        });
     }).finally(result => {
         return result;        // Result should be bool, false should stop each loop
     }); 
});
```

I want to wait for how each iteration resolves in the wait command, before either stoping the loop or continuing to the next iteration.

Comment: This is not what promises are supposed to work. To achieve that, you will need to chain your promises.

Comment: @MetallimaX That is what I'm trying to achieve here, the problem is that the first promise never resolves

Answer (score -2):

You should try to use the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) pattern.

Comment: Cypress does not use actual promises, it uses an internal [command queue](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#The-Cypress-Command-Queue). Therefore, using async/await is not possible.